# okhttp3 compatibility issue with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: okhttp

```java
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Request
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder


def clientId = "*****"
def tenantId = "*****"
def clientSecret = "*****"
def resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
def scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")

ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
   .clientId(clientId)
   .tenantId(tenantId)
   .clientSecret(clientSecret)
   .build()

def authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential)

GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
   .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
   .buildClient()
```

Returns
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.connectTimeout(Ljava/time/Duration;)Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;

Library versions:

- azure-core-1.42.0
- azure-identity-1.10.0
- jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.2
- microsoft-graph-5.68.0
- microsoft-graph-core-2.0.19
- okhttp-4.11.0
- reactive-core-3.5.9
- reactive-streams-1.04

Unable to connect to Microsoft Graph